# `snap` fails from inside docker container

Tags: snap, docker

I pulled the latest Ubuntu image from hub.docker.com

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
```

Everything downloaded correctly so I launched the container

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu
```

I installed `snapd` into the container

```
# apt update
...
All packages are up to date.
# apt install snapd
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/...
...
done.
```

When I try to login, I am getting a failure

```
# snap login
2017/04/20 18:06:04.729212 main.go:220: WARNING: cannot create syslog logger
Email address: <me@email.com>
Password of "me@email.com":
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/login: dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I even tried `sudo` just to be sure...

```
# sudo snap login
bash: sudo: command not found
```

Comment: It seems `snapd` daemon is not running, could you post the output of `systemctl status snapd.s*`

Comment: @user.dz `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4):

It takes more than that to get snapd working inside a Docker container. Check out Ogra's container here:
https://github.com/ogra1/snapd-docker